# Reflex golang with docker, docker-compose and makefile

Tags: docker, go, makefile, docker-compose, dockerfile

hope you all are fine !

I read a lot about this problem but doesn't find something work for me ..

Explain context:
I'm making an rest api with go but the code show here are fake code for readability.
I'm using docker with docker-compose who build a dockerfile who CMD a makefile and I've a problem with reflex for dev env. Reflex start but doesn't reload after change.
I probably miss something, I'm new to Go and Docker :)

Ok code time:

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - appsrc:/app
    environment:
      CODE_ENV: dev
    networks:
      - apbp-network

networks:
  apbp-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  appsrc:
```

who call my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN make --no-print-directory install

CMD make --no-print-directory run
```

who call my Makefile

```
GO_PROJECT_NAME := test

go_prep_build:
    @echo "\n....Preparing installation environment for $(GO_PROJECT_NAME)...."
    go get github.com/cespare/reflex

go_dep_install:
    @echo "\n....Installing dependencies for $(GO_PROJECT_NAME)...."
    go mod download

go_build:
    @echo "\n....Building $(GO_PROJECT_NAME)...."
    go build -o test ./cmd/test

go_run:
    @echo "\n....Running $(GO_PROJECT_NAME)...."
    ./test


# Project rules
install:
    $(MAKE) go_prep_build
    $(MAKE) go_dep_install
    $(MAKE) go_build

run:
    reflex --start-service -r '\.go$$' make restart


restart:
    @$(MAKE) go_build
    @$(MAKE) go_run

.PHONY: go_prep_build go_dep_install go_build go_run install run restart reflex
```

my ./cmd/test file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello world")
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Everythings work well just my reflex command doesn't reload after change for exemple change hello world to hello world 2 doesn't rebuild.

my output:

```
app_1  | reflex --start-service -r '\.go$' make restart
app_1  | [00] Starting service
app_1  | [00] 
app_1  | [00] ....Building apbp....
app_1  | [00] go build -o test ./cmd/test
app_1  | [00] 
app_1  | [00] ....Running apbp....
app_1  | [00] ./test
```

I'm literaly stuck with it I think it's a little thing I missunderstand so if someone can help with explain that really welcome :)

Thank to read and if you need more informations ask me :)

Comment: You might find it easier to use an actual local development environment, than try to convince Docker to simulate one.  Have your Dockerfile `RUN make install`, and then have its default command be to start the built application `CMD ./test`, and remove the `volumes:` from the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hey David, thank for your time ! Sorry but I don't understand what you want to explain. My code is simplest than my real code I've multiple container with multiple build to run in order like migration and all. But yes reflex work without docker. Can you explain me what you want to say? I'm sorry I'm reallly new to it

Comment: see this repo https://github.com/acim/go-reflex and check their restart command. It is `-sr '\.go$' -- /usr/local/bin/build.sh`

Comment: Thank mh-cbon, but I read that as I did. `-sr '\.go$' -- /usr/local/bin/build.sh` the /usr/local/bin/build.sh part it's just the command who run when reflex see change. But in my case reflex doesn't see change and my command it's just a makefile command. Maybe I'm wrong it's just how I read the doc ..

Comment: Just a comment to encourage you: I only use local Docker dev environments (installing stuff belongs to the 90s!) I had a problem when adding a Go API, by your question/answer solved this for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was just my volume that was blocking the reload but I don't understand why so if anyone can explain it, it would be welcome !

I just change my docker-compose.yaml to :

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      CODE_ENV: dev
    networks:
      - apbp-network

networks:
  apbp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Thank for yours responses and time !

Comment: The original form was making a copy of your application code in a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  The first time it ran, the code would get copied into the volume from the image; on later runs, the (old) content in the volume would replace what was in the image.  Other than the initial image build, nothing had any connection to your host filesystem at all.

Comment: Ohhhhh make clear ok I missunderstood that part ok that sound logic now ! Thank David !